# Azure Powershell script to swap Azure App Service (website) deployment slots

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm looking for a way to use Azure PowerShell commands to do a deployment swap for an Azure App Service (previously Azure Websites).  All of the posts I've seen say to use the command

```
Move-Deployment -ServiceName
```

but that appears to only be valid for cloud services and swapping between Production and Staging predefined slots.

I have a website with deployment slots that I've defined and I can use the following command to get information about the website site, but I don't see how to swap it:

```
Get-AzureWebsite -Name "sitenamehere" -Slot test
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot [[-Name] <String> ] [[-Slot1] <String> ] [[-Slot2] <String> ] [-Force] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed.  I had found a blog post finally and was posting an answer at the same time as you.  Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that! 
I also wanted to clarify after checking out the link you posted, my reading was from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722464.aspx) which stated the cmdlet could only be run on websites with two slots. After reading your link, I realized it simply throws an error if you have more than two slots and fail to specify which to switch.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the command

```
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name "sitenamehere"
```

More details are provided in this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harikharan/archive/2015/01/01/swap-slots-in-azure-web-site-when-there-are-2-or-more-staging-slots-using-azure-powershell.aspx