# PowerShell command to perform swap with preview

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I have an ***Azure Function App*** with two deployment slots. Is there a PowerShell command to ***swap*** deployment slots ***with preview***?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, you can use the below powershell commands to swap the slots with preview.

```
Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $site -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction ApplySlotConfig
```

the above command applies the current staging slot's setting values to the target slot

and then use the below command to finish the swap

```
Switch-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $site -SourceSlotName staging -DestinationSlotName production -SwapWithPreviewAction CompleteSlotSwap
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [manage Azure Web App Deployment Slots](https://ruslany.net/2016/10/using-powershell-to-manage-azure-web-app-deployment-slots/#:%7E:text=%20Using%20Powershell%20to%20manage%20Azure%20Web%20App,the%20staging%20slot%20works%20as%20expected.%20More%20)
2. [Azure Powershell script to swap Azure App Service deployment slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765524/azure-powershell-script-to-swap-azure-app-service-website-deployment-slots)

Comment: I have Azure Function Apps. Could I use these commands for function apps?

Comment: I tried the above commands however app settings are set incorrectly. When I swap with preview via Azure Portal, app settings are set correctly. Why is that?

Comment: How do I verify that 1st command has run successfully before running the above 2nd command in PowerShell?

Comment: @user989988, after performing the first command you can check with ```$stagingSite = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $site -Slot staging
$stagingSite.SiteConfig.AppSettings``` and see the app setting values have changed.